# Does requiring SSL matter if using AWS RDS and AWS EC2 in a VPC

Tags: amazon-rds, ssl

I have a MySQL RDS DB and am connecting it through an EC2 instance.

My RDS isn't publicly accessible, so I think it can only be connected to through my EC2 instances.

I see at this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html that you can set up SSL with your RDS.

Does setting up SSL with your RDS matter if your RDS is protected?

Answer (score 5):

This question -- and its answer -- are primarily regulatory/compliance matters.

If you need to comply with a standard that mandates encryption in transit between systems on the network, then you need SSL on RDS because the AWS network only *isolates* your VPC's traffic from the machines in all other VPCs -- the traffic is not actually encrypted on the wire as it traverses the cables, routers, and switches within the availability zone or region.

Traffic between systems in a VPC is still traveling unencrypted over the AWS infrastructure within the region, where it is *theoretically possible* for the traffic to be intercepted by a malicious actor who was able to compromise the AWS infrastructure. Such a compromise is considered highly unlikely, as there are protective controls in place such that it should almost necessarily require physical access and a conspiracy among multiple AWS insiders, but "highly unlikely" isn't the same as "impossible."